# How to select an item in multi group listbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I can select items in listbox using the following jquery

```
$('#id option[value=<?php echo $row; ?>]').attr('selected','selected');
```

But it is not working for `optgroup`, Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You want to select all items in a specific optgroup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#id option[value="<?php echo $row; ?>"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

You have to use quotes to write php strings.

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using php to construct javascript is not a wise practice because you can't utilize browser caching and it becomes more difficult to reuse the code. Also, `optgroup` is not for selecting, the purpose of the tag is to simply group options within a `select`. If you're trying to detect which `optgroup` contains the user selected `option`, you have to use a different approach. Please provide the markup representing the whole `select` and also specify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGLAj/

```
<select multiple=true>
    <optgroup value="coucou" >
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup value="ciao" >
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

$(' optgroup[value=coucou]').children().attr('selected','selected');
```